# Setting background programmatically overrides drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-drawable

I have a `ListView` and I have a `Drawable` for each item in the `ListView` to highlight each row when it's selected/pressed.  I also have a custom adapter where I'm programatically setting the background color of each row (I want to have alternating background colors).  This is a new feature I added and before adding the code the rows would highlight blue, but after they do not highlight.  Not sure how to fix it.  Here is what I have:

**ListView item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
>    
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/ListingTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />

    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ListingFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        ListView lv = getListView();

        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, android.view.MenuItem item) {
                }
        }
    }

     /* ADAPTER */
     private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
     {       
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
        {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            }
            else 
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            if (position % 2 == 0)
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            else
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            return(convertView);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hi, I tried your code in my local machine, it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on dum's answer, you don't need to do all that work in code.

#### Drawable A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

#### Drawable B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/gray" />
</selector>
```

#### In your Adapter:

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.A);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing the drawable with plain color, first create a new drawable programmatically and set the states just like in your xml and then set colors for each state. then try replacing your background with your programmatically created drwable.